# Shopware 5 Controller cant find templates

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware5

I am trying to call a template using the controller but I cant get the template to show. I registered the Controller and the subscriber inside of the serivces.xml. The name of the folder that holds the template is the same name as the Controller `lorem_questions`. I cant find the problem. Here are some sniptes of my code.

Subscriber:

```
        public static function getSubscribedEvents()
        {
            return [
                'Enlight_Controller_Action_PreDispatch' => 'addTemplateDir',
                ];
        }

        public function addTemplateDir()
        {
            $this->templateManager->addTemplateDir($this->pluginDirectory . '/Resources/views/');

        }
```

Controller:

```
class LoremQuestions extends Enlight_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

    public function loremQuestionsPrinterAction()
    {

       die($this->View()->assign("name", 2));
    }
```

templates:

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/index/index.tpl"}
{block name="frontend_index_navigation_categories_top_include"}
    <h1>yhfsajf</h1>
    <h1>fsakfsa</h1>
    <h1>fsakfsa</h1>
{/block}
```

or:

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/index/index.tpl"}
{block name="frontend_detail_tabs_navigation_inner" append}
    <a href="#" class="tab--link" title="Tab" data-tabName="tab">Fragen</a>
{/block}

{block name="frontend_detail_tabs_content_inner" append}
    {debug}
    <div class="tab--container">
        <div class="tab--header>">
            <a href="#" class="tab--title">Fragen</a>
        </div>

        <div class="tab--preview">
            <a href="#" class="tab--link">um die Fragen zu sehen hier Klicken</a>
        </div>

        <div class="tab--content">
            <div class="content--description">
                <h1>{$name}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{/block}
```

services:

```
        <!--  Subscriber    -->
        <service id="lorem_questions.subscriber.frontend_subscriber"
                 class="LoremQuestions\Subscriber\FrontendSubscriber">
            <argument>%lorem_questions.plugin_dir%</argument>
            <argument id="template" type="service"/>
            <tag name="shopware.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
        <!--  Controller    -->
        <service id="LoremQuestions\Controller\Frontend\LoremQuestions">
            <tag name="shopware.controller" module="frontend" controller="LoremQuestions"/>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing and renaming the folder that contained the Templates and the Controller.php it self so instead of having`LoremQuestions` as a controller I deleted it and created another Controller and named it `Questions` after that I deleted the folder that hold the Templates and made a new one so instead `lorem_questions`with the name of `questions` and re-registered the Controller inside of the services.xml and it works now. I am getting the values inside of the Templates can someone please Explain to me why it worked after changing the names?

serives.xml now Looks like this :

```
        <service id="LoremQuestions\Controller\Frontend\Questions">
            <tag name="shopware.controller" module="frontend" controller="Questions"/>
        </service>
```

Comment: I know why I ran into this problem Shopware 5 is very specific when it comes to names and Letter cases after more testing I fond out the one of the Directory that I created didn't match the exact name of the Directory in the themes and this did lead to an error where the controller and the Template couldn't work together.